# Select particular element with common class selenium

Tags: java, selenium

```html
<div class="ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled" style="width: 100%;"><div class="ant-select-selection
            ant-select-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><div class="ant-select-selection__rendered"><div unselectable="unselectable" class="ant-select-selection__placeholder" style="display: block; user-select: none;">Select</div></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="unselectable" style="user-select: none;"><b></b></span></div></div>
            
            
            
            
            
  <div class="ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled" style="width: 100%;"><div class="ant-select-selection
            ant-select-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0"><div class="ant-select-selection__rendered"><div unselectable="unselectable" class="ant-select-selection__placeholder" style="display: block; user-select: none;">Select</div></div><span class="ant-select-arrow" unselectable="unselectable" style="user-select: none;"><b></b></span></div></div>
```

I need to select the second element in DOM , Both elements do not have ID and have the same class.When I test this on chrome I get two elements with same xpath

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled')]
```

I tried indexing but my program throws Given xpath expression is wrong exception.

I tried indexing like:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*(@class='ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled')[2]"));
```

How can this be achieved in selenium?

Comment: Please share relevant html code in text format

Comment: You have parentheses instead of brackets in your xpath. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled'][2]"));`

Comment: I tried but still receiving org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class='ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled'])[2]"));
```

Comment: I tried the same but it throws exception saying xpath is incorrect.

Comment: I think you should remove the parentheses and leave only the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled'][2]"));
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ant-select-lg')][2]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Left hand side are your elements as appeared on a test html page, right hand side is selection of second "Select" element shown with  `//div[@class='ant-select-lg homeLocation_select_dummy ant-select ant-select-enabled'][2]`. Please do Inspect element on your page with Chrome and Ctrl+F with this xpath and see if this selection is working before clicking the element in your Java code with Selenium driver.

[image]

Comment: Thanks will this work if elemets have different parent?because I have similar condition where elments have different parent

Comment: @PrashantRaghav, solution was based on the html snippet you posted. If there are different parents and names are distinct then solution should be easier. I would suggest, please add more html to the question to get better understanding of the problem.