# Select an element with duplicate class name with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, class, href

```html
<ul class="k9GMp ">
  <li class="Y8-fY "><span class="-nal3 "><span class="g47SY ">2</span> posts</span>
  </li>
  <li class="Y8-fY "><a class="-nal3 " href="/username/followers/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY " title="590">590</span> followers</a></li>
  <li class="Y8-fY "><a class="-nal3 " href="/username/following/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY ">479</span> following</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hi, selenium noob here working in Python. I want to open the 'followers' page on Instagram (to see how many people follow me) and it seems `posts`, `followers`, and `following` all have the same class names, from the `<li>`, `<span>`, `<span>` (pardon my bad HTML, not my specialty).

-I have tried using `driver.find_element_by_link_text('/username/followers/')` and receive `NoSuchElementException`

I understand there is a [similar question in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117249/select-particular-element-with-common-class-selenium) here however this doesn't help me as I need it in Python.

Additionally, the follower page on instagram.com is a popup box on the url `instagram.com/username/followers/`, however going to that url yourself will autodirect you to `instagram.com/username/`

Please let me know:

a. Why my `link_text` code doesn't work (yes I understand it's not a full link however that's what was in the HTML as the `href`)

b. How can I get the follower page/popup to open up from selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='-nal3' and contains(text(),'followers')]").click()
```